# How to search a file in File Cabinet of netsuite?

Tags: c#

I am new to netsuite. I need to search a file in File Cabinate and for that I think I need to call 
getSelectValue method. Can anybody help me how to call the method (what should be parameters) in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
var myFilterByList = new GetSelectFilterByFieldValueList(new
GetSelectFilterByFieldValue[]{new GetSelectFilterByFieldValue(null,"entity","10")});//Adujst parameters

    var getSelectValueFieldDescription = new GetSelectValueFieldDescription(yourEntity,
null, "itemList", "item", null, null, myFilterByList); //Adjust parameters

var result = GetSelectValue(getSelectValueFieldDescription,1);
```

Link : http://www.celigo.com/ns/downloads/suiteTalk/samples/net/svcMgr/docs/HTML/html/ea4e3442-6fcd-b2eb-4b41-153689a06735.htm

```
public virtual GetSelectValueResult GetSelectValue(
    GetSelectValueFieldDescription fieldDescription,
    int pageIndex
)
```

Comment: add this GetSelectFilterByFieldValueList in parameter of GetSelectValueFieldDescription